# ROBLOX - How can I convert a Vector3 position into a CFrame one?

Tags: lua, roblox

Is there any way I can convert a Vector3 Position to a CFrame one? If so please let me know.

Comment: You can always check the [CFrame documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame)

Answer (score 0):

```
local pos=workspace.Part.Position
print(CFrame.new(pos))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work:

```lua
local CFRAME_VALUE = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(YOUR_VECTOR3_VALUES))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Vector3 in a CFrame, making it one:

```
local mycframe = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(1,2,3))
```